# Do I need to add @2x and @3x images for iPad application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, image-size

I have some doubts about the dimensions of images

1. Do I need to add `@2x` and `@3x` images for iPads ?
2. What would be the width and height of Splash(Launch) image (@1x image) ?
3. What would be the width and height of Background image (@1x image) ?

Comment: Do you have `ipad only application` ?  what is your deployment target ?  and are you using `LaunchImage` or `storyboard` as launch screen ?

Comment: Yes. iPad only app. deployment target is 8.2. I'm using launch image

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/image-size-and-resolution/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your deployment target is iOS 7 or later then you require two launch images 1x and 2x of size 768 x 1024 pixels and 1536 x 2048 pixels respectively for portrait and vice versa for landscape for iPads!

You can easily know this from the attributes inspector - expected size after clicking any 1x or 2x image from `launchImage` from assets!

And you do not require 3x images for iPads!

Comment: The iPad pro uses 3x images

Comment: yeah but apple no longer will supporting `launch image` so that they don't add `3x` slot in asset for launch image for `ipad pro`,they recommend that app should use storyboard instead of launch image. But apple have add appicon with `2x` resolution of `83.5 pt`, so you can't say that `ipad` uses `3x` image set whether is it's resolution high then also! @Alex

Comment: iPad require 1x and 2x images only. Only "Plus" iPhone and iPhone X use @3x

Comment: @Alex I don't think that is correct. [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/) 3x devices are iPhone X, iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 7 Plus, and iPhone 6s Plus. And that all other high-resolution iOS devices use 2x. There's no mention of iPad Pro among the 3x devices.

Comment: @peacetype It looks like you are correct, thank you for the heads up. It looks like the behavior described by Ashish-Systematix no longer exists in the current version of Xcode (I noticed this behavior as well, but that was at the original time of my comment). Right now any iPad will ignore the 3x images unless there are no 1x or 2x images provided. In short, no current iPad uses 3x images. Although, there could in the future I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

1.Do I need to add @2x and @3x images for iPad applications

> From iOS 8.0 need only @2x and @3x images for both iPhone and iPad
> applications.
>
> for the @2x and @3x, The device will automatically pick
> the right one, you no need to care about it, just make sure that there are @2x assets with twice the point size and @3x assets with thrice the point size in pixels.

2.What would be the width and height of Splash(Launch) image (@1x image) ?

[Please visit here for answer](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2015/03/09/launch-images-on-ios-with-adobe-air/)

3.What would be the width and height of Background image (@1x image) ?

> You need @2x and @3x size for background images also.

Comment: There is no @3x ipad hardware.

Comment: yes, but from iOS 8.0 @1x is never used, and 2x is using for all devices, 
but if you develop an app for both iPhone and iPad then 3x image is required otherwise image is squashed in iPad.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about iPad devices.

Comment: @Ashish-Systematix I originally found this to be accurate, but it looks like this behavior has been updated and no longer exists in Xcode 9.2+